# Jquery hover function regarding image replacement on fadein/fadeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I'm trying to replace image links for two different divs when the third div is being hovered over. How can I do this cause my jquery is not correct and not concise. I do realize that I cant do double this.attr haha. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
$('#minerallink').hover(function() { // On mouseenter
    $('#brainicon, #stomachicon').stop(true, true).fadeOut(function() { // Fade out the image, and when done
    $(this).attr('src', 'health-tips/images/images/medicineman-icons-dark_01.png', ).fadeIn();
    $(this).attr('src', 'health-tips/images/images/medicineman-icons-dark_04.png').fadeIn(); // Change its source and fade in
    });
    $('#manpic5').stop(true, true).fadeOut(function() { // Fade out the image, and when done
    $(this).attr('src', 'health-tips/images/images/medicineman-dark_05.png').fadeIn(); // Change its source and fade in
    });
 }, 
 function() { // On mouseleave - reverse the process
    $('#brainicon, #stomachicon').stop(true, true).fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).attr('src', 'health-tips/images/images/medicineman-icons_01.png').fadeIn();
        $(this).attr('src', 'health-tips/images/images/medicineman-icons_04.png').fadeIn();
         });
    $('#manpic5').stop(true, true).fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).attr('src', 'health-tips/images/images/medicineman_05.png').fadeIn();
    });
 });
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the .stop(true,true) ?

Comment: @gibberish - I was just trying chained calls before but that really isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

split the 2 id's like so:

```
$('#stomachicon').stop(true, true).fadeOut(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'health-tips/images/images/medicineman-icons-dark_04.png').fadeIn();
});

$('#brainicon').stop(true, true).fadeOut(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'health-tips/images/images/medicineman-icons-dark_01.png', ).fadeIn();
});
```

and do this for the rest

Comment: I agree but if I have multiple divs that I would want to have the image replaced, is there no way to just combine them without having to split up?